# Thumb RCL reconstruction - Abductor Pollicis Brevis vs Palmaris Longus

Tags: surgery, hand, ligament, thumb

Tearing the Radial Collateral Ligament in the thumb seems to be way less common than tearing the Ulnar Collateral Ligament in the thumb and so I'm having trouble finding relevant information on Google.

I found the following journals suggesting that the Abductor Pollicis Brevis Tendon can be used for RCL reconstruction:

<sup>Iba, Kousuke: **[Reconstruction of Chronic Thumb Metacarpophalangeal Joint Radial Collateral Ligament Injuries With a Half-Slip of the Abductor Pollicis Brevis Tendon](https://www.jhandsurg.org/article/S0363-5023%2813%2900821-6/abstract?code=yjhsu-site)**; Journal of Hand Surgery</sup>

<sup>Horche: **[Radial collateral ligament repair of the thumb metacarpophalangeal joint using the abductor pollicis brevis tendon.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16462331/)** Plastic Reconstruction Surgery.</sup>

Another options seems to be using the Palmaris Longus for the reconstruction. I haven't been able to find any literature on how this compares to using the APB in terms of success rate, expected recovery time etc. I found a procedure called Camitz Transfer but I gather this is for carpal tunnel rather than ligament injuries of the thumb.

Are both procedures established reconstructions of the RCL? Which is preferable in what cases?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. We can’t give personal medical advice, so your best chance is to ask if using the Palmaris Longus for reconstruction of the thumb rcl is a standard procedure or even better, asking from the viewpoint of a professional (which will be more appreciated and still provide you with the relevant info): When to use PL and when to use APB for reconstruction. With a bit of refinement, I think this can be an excellent question!

Comment: @Narusan thanks for the feedback - that's what I was trying to go for with "what is the current best practice" rather than specifically for me. But I'll edit it to make it even more generic

Comment: I have tweaked the question a little bit further. Please disagree and edit again!